# Volatility estimation: sampling frequency and scaling

Tags: high-frequency, garch

I have a year long stock data sampled at 5 min frequency and would like to estimate monthly volatility using it. I am thinking using GARCH or TGARCH for volatility estimation. However, I am not sure if at frequency I should estimating volatility. After that should I scale volatility by square root of appropriate period?

Comment: 1) For estimation of monthly vol, data sampled at daily interval should be fine enough. 2) Yes, you should scale vol using the square root rule: i.e., monthly_vol = daily_vol * sqrt(21), assuming there are 21 business days in a month.

Comment: Square root scaling is known to overestimate the variance. Following paper makes this point and suggests a way around: http://www.ssc.upenn.edu/~fdiebold/papers/paper18/dsi.pdf

Answer (score -1):

You can try out a range of frequencies and then pick the one with the lowest fitting error (e.g. Root Mean Squared Error).